# Ensure UI Thread isn't interrupted

Tags: android

I have a GridView full of somewhat complicated views, that are computed based on results downloaded on the fly from the internet in an AsyncTask.  While the view is being downloaded, it shows a default:

```
imageView.setImageDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
```

When the AsyncTask finishes it gets a Bitmap that was computed for it.  I am using an ExecutorService to enable AsyncTask parallelization:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
        loaderPool = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(backendManager.getBackendApplicationContext()
                .getResources()
                .getInteger(R.integer.loader_thread_count));
}
```

(I've currently set R.integer.loader_thread_count to 10)

And I start those AsyncTask's as:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
    newTask.executeOnExecutor(loaderPool);
} else {
    newTask.execute();  // Pre-Honeycomb Post-Donut is parallelized by default.
}
```

I make sure to set the thread priority in the AsyncTask so that it doesn't try to compete with anything else:

```
@Override
protected Object doInBackground(Object... params) {
    if (isCancelled()) {
        return null;
    }

    // just in case
    android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);
...
```

But, the ui feels jerky when scrolling the GridView.  The issue seems to be that the main thread is getting pre-empted too often:

[image: Traceview of running process]

I would like a large number of threads for when there is high network latency, so that they can all be blocking on network io when necessary.  However, I only want those threads to run when the ui has essentially nothing else to do; I'm fine showing transparent views for a while while everything loads, so long as the ui is responsive while it is loading (there are some text views and stuff too so it's not just a blank screen).

How can I instruct android to give greater priority to my ui thread, and/or less priority to my AsyncTasks?

Comment: Have you tried [`setPriority()` on `Thread`](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/lang/Thread.html#setPriority%28int%29) to adjust downward the priority of your threads in the pool?

Comment: @CommonsWare, I tried your recommendation and put " Thread.currentThread().setPriority(Thread.MIN_PRIORITY);" at the top of my doInBackground() - but traceview said my AsyncTask's were running for 49% of the cpu time (graph looked more or less like what I posted initially).  Also tried "android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_LOWEST);", 37% :(

Comment: There's a big difference between a Thread and a Process and I don't think you want to change the priority of your process.

Answer (score 2):

I would like a better answer, but for now this seemed to help a bunch.

While the docs claim for the higher thread priorities that "Applications can not normally change to 
this priority", as of a few years ago that was a lie, and seems (?) to apparently still be a lie - https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/b2SKprSxPvw

As such rather than make the background threads more backgrounded, I made the ui thread more foregrounded in Activity.onCreate().  In case they disallow this sort of thing in the future, I wrap it with a try/catch:

```
try {
        android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DISPLAY);
} catch (Throwable t) {}
```